# Query regarding format of Azure Subscription id

Tags: azure, subscription

I wanted to check what all characters can be present in Subscription id of Azure Subscription.  I saw documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.models.subscription.id?view=azure-dotnet)  but it mentions format of id as something like 0000-0000-0000-000000000000. It does no tells me what all characters  are valid in the format. e.g. can Subscription id contain "_" or any other character

I tried referring  documentation but could not find the required information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure subscription ID is a globally unique identifier (GUID).
The following article discuss how to validate GUID using Regular Expression. I think it would help you [link here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-validate-guid-globally-unique-identifier-using-regular-expression/)

[image: guid doc]

Comment: here is the RegEx @"^(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})$"

Comment: The [Micosoft Rest API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/defenderforcloud/tasks/get-subscription-level-task?view=rest-defenderforcloud-2015-06-01-preview&tabs=HTTP), mentions this Azure subscription ID Regex pattern: `^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-){3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}$`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the RegEx for your question

```
@"^(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})$"
```